# how to show initial routes when click on each tab using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

in the tab bar I used two tabs for each tab as created separate navigator
here is my code:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Settings: SettingsStack,
  }
);
```

We start on the HomeScreen and navigate to DetailsScreen. Then we use the tab bar to switch to the SettingsScreen and navigate to ProfileScreen. After this sequence of operations is done, all 4 of the screens are mounted! If I use the tab bar to switch back to the HomeStack I was displaying the Home screen but I want the HomeScreen to need to display instead of the detail screen.

Any suggestions much helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use navigation.popToTop().

Comment: did you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually surprisingly tricky with react-navigation.

One way to achieve this globally is by using the [tabBarOnPress callback](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress) to reset the stack every time a tab is changed:

```js
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeStack,
  Settings: SettingsStack,
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
      defaultHandler(); // Switch tab
      if (navigation.state.index > 0) { // In case the stack is not positioned at the first screen
        const resetAction = StackActions.reset({ // Reset the stack
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: navigation.state.routes[0].routeName })
          ],
        });
        navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Whenever the user switches tab, the new stack will move to the first index in case it was not already.

Comment: Hi, how it will be done with react navigation 5? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For thos who look for a solution in `react-navigation 6`, you can use either the prop `unmount` at the top level of the bottom tabs navigator or `listeners` at the nested navigator level like so

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabNavigator = ({}) => {

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      ...
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeStack"
        component={HomeStackNavigator}
        listeners={({navigation, route}) => ({     // Use this for a specific navigator
          tabPress: e => {
            // Prevent default action
            e.preventDefault();
            // Reset the stack navigator on tab press
            navigation.navigate('HomeStack', {screen: 'Home'});
          },
      })}  
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

or

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabNavigator = ({}) => {

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={() => ({
        ...
        unmountOnBlur: true,     // Or use this as a global behavior
      })}
    >
      ...
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```